# Update/Insert sql table from SSAS cube

Tags: t-sql, ssas

Is it possible, preferably using tsql or MDX, to read data from cube and use it to update or add records in a sql table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OPENQUERY can do this

[How to perform a SQL Server distributed query with OLAP Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218592)